# Linearity and time invariance

Tags: signal, control-system

If the input of an unknown system is shown by:

\$x(t)= u(t)-u(t-1)\$

which results in the following output:

\$y(t)=u(t)-u(t-3/2)\$

then what can be said about the linearity and time invariance of this system?

Comment: Is not u(t - 1.5) the same as the average of u(t - 2) and u(t - 3)?

Comment: @Andyaka: I understand u(t) as the unit step, and then the answer is no. Maybe mac should clarify what is u(t).

Comment: you are right. By u(t) I mean the unit step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing conclusive can be said about linearity and/or time invariance.

For linearity one would need at least (!) to know the response of the system to \$A u(t) - A u(t-1)\$. (e.g. \$2 u(t) - 2 u(t-1)\$ could result in (or in something completely different to) \$2 u(t) - 2 u(t-3/2)\$)

For time invariance one needs to know at least (!) the response to \$ u(t-t_0) -  u(t-1-t_0)\$. It can, but does not need to be \$u(t-t_0) - u(t-3/2-t_0)\$. So it is inconclusive either.

Comment: Thanks Andreas.What you mentioned is known as the standard method for such problems. But the question here is that how to apply this method(or any other) for this case to get the exact result.

Comment: @mac: I dont understand that. The point is, that you, in your question, only have a single, specific response of a system and from that one cannot infer anything about the system's general behavior (which is the response to all possible inputs).

Comment: What conditions should be assumed to be able to give a specific answer?

Comment: @mac: sorry I accidentially placed my commend in the wrong place: Here it is: see second sentence of en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system and second paragraph of en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system for mathematical definition

Comment: you are completely right. Thanks for your responses.